# Where can I find the Annotation(s) for test classes?

Tags: testing

I've seen lots of examples of tests like:

```
/**
 * My test description.
 *
 * @group mymodule
 */
class MyModuleTest extends KernelTestBase { }
```

I know what `@group mymodule` is and how that annotation works, but what other information can I put there? or, more importantly, where is that information defined? I can’t find it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, these are annotations. See https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/annotations.html

Specifically in Drupal the @group annotation is mandatory. The @requires annotation is optional. The description is discovered from the lines above the first annotation or, if specified, from @coversDefaultClass.

See [TestDiscovery::getTestInfo](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Test%21TestDiscovery.php/function/TestDiscovery%3A%3AgetTestInfo/9.3.x).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[@group is one of](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/annotations.html#group) the many available PHPUnit annotations.

Comment: Oh, of course they are just PHPUnit annotations. That makes more sense. Thank you!